# How to read or calculate pdf page margins

Tags: .net, pdf, pdfsharp, pdfsharpcore

Is there a way to calculate pdf margins for any given pdf ?

I tried few approaches via PdfSharpCore library and it didn't work for all pdfs.

1. comparing MediaBox & TrimBox.
2. comparing MediaBox & Page.

more info https://www.pdf2go.com/blog/what-are-pdf-boxes

```
    public Margins CalculateMargins(PdfPage page, PdfRectangle mediaBox, PdfRectangle trimBox)
    {
        // Didn't work; using Trim box (not being set for all pdfs) 
        //double leftMargin = XUnit.FromPoint( trimBox.X1 - mediaBox.X1).Inch; 
        //double topMargin = XUnit.FromPoint(trimBox.Y1 - mediaBox.Y1).Inch;
        //double rightMargin = trimBox.X2 > 0 ? XUnit.FromPoint(mediaBox.X2 - trimBox.X2).Inch : 0;
        //double bottomMargin = trimBox.Y2 > 0 ? XUnit.FromPoint(mediaBox.Y2 - trimBox.Y2).Inch : 0;

        //Didn't work; Calculate margins based on the page size and content size
        double leftMargin = XUnit.FromPoint(page.MediaBox.X1).Inch;
        double rightMargin = XUnit.FromPoint(page.MediaBox.Width - page.Width.Point).Inch;
        double topMargin = XUnit.FromPoint(page.MediaBox.Height - page.Height.Point).Inch;
        double bottomMargin = XUnit.FromPoint(page.MediaBox.Y2).Inch;

        this.PageMargins = new Margins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        return PageMargins;
    }
```

second question;

Is there a way to iterate through all elements in the pdf page and find their rendering positions to find the distance between page and the elements ?

something like;

```
 public void IteratePdfElements(string pdfFilePath)
 {
     // Get the content of the page
     using PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFilePath, PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly);

     PdfPage page = pdfDocument.Pages[0]; // Get the first page

     foreach (PdfItem? content in page.Contents.Elements)
     {
         PdfSharpCore.Pdf.Advanced.PdfReference pdfContent = (PdfSharpCore.Pdf.Advanced.PdfReference)content;

         Debug.WriteLine(content.ToString());
```

Thanks

Comment: Ghostscript's bbox device will return the area marked by marking elements on the page. Subtract that from the media size and you get some kind of margin, but since margins are merely white space, and PDF doesn't carry any 'margin' metadata its an approximation at best.